# Javascript not bound on thymeleaf fragment update

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a page fragment returned from a spring controller as a result of an Ajax form submit. The fragment updates a table in the page. The table contains buttons that use jquery onclick function selecting button class.

The jquery select does not work if the table is returned as part of a fragment, the javascript seems not to be bound to the replaced html in the page even though the classes etc are all the same as previously.

Any ideas how to get the javascript to work with the returned HTML in the thymeleaf fragment?

Comment: That's exactly it. Thank you